# Resize logic to maintain a fixed corner after rotate in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, rotation, resize

How to calculate or logic behind to get **translate x & y while resize(with one fixed corner) after rotate.**

#### Below image shows corner based resize works perfect with unrotated div.(`rotate:0deg`)

[image]

I handled center based rotate and resize without any problem.

But the problem is, i need a **fixed corner when resize a rotated div.**

When resize a rotated div, using **bottom-right handle, top-left needs to remains fixed**, likewise opposite corners need to fixed position.

#### HTML code:

```
<div class="box" style="transform: translate(132px, 190px) rotate(45deg); width: 295px; height: 234px;">
<div>
```

#### Javascript code:

```
function rotate(){
  //Here i update angle
}

function resize(){
 //Here i update translate x & y, width & height

 switch (handle) {
   case 'bottom-right':
     x = previous_x - ? ;   // logic to get translate x when resize a rotated div.
     y = previous_y + ? ;   // logic to get translate y when resize a rotated div.
     break;
   case 'bottom-left':
     x = previous_x - ? ;
     y = previous_y + ? ;
     break;
   case 'top-left':
     x = previous_x - ? ;
     y = previous_y + ? ;
     break;
   case 'top-right':
     x = previous_x - ? ;
     y = previous_y + ? ;
     break;
   default:
 }
}
```

I checked [Canva](https://www.canva.com) website, the transform manager div **translate x and y gets updated while resize a rotated div to maintain a fixed corner**.

Anybody help me to calculate translate x and y values using rotated angle to maintain a fixed corner.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could just set a transform-origin using CSS so you don't have to calculate the translate to compensate :

```
.box{transform-origin: 0 100% 0;}
```

Link to [W3C doc](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform-origin.asp)

Example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akw9b51u/)

Comment: Yes its working, i up-voted and its one of the way.  But doing changes in css property while start dragging corner handle is not the way i need. 
Are you visited [Canva](https://www.canva.com) website.? Is there using transform-origin property to fix corners..? I need translate x and y calculations. Please check canva or give me relevant logic they used..

Comment: OMG... No one here to help me..?